# A non planar graph has either five vertices of degree at least 4 or six vertices of degree at least 3 (Without using Kuratowski's theorem)

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

This was given as an exercise in my textbook before Kuratowski's theorem (a graph is non planar if and only if it has a subgraph homeomorphic to K$_5$ or K$_{3,3}$) was even introduced. So, there must be a simple intuitive solution to this problem. I was wondering if someone could help me solve this because I am not even close!

Comment: Have you tried induction on $|V|$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume, to the contrary, that our graph have no more than 5 vertices of degree at least 3
and no more than 4 vertices of degree at least 4.

1. Then all other vertices of the graph have degree at most 2.
2. The graph remains nonplanar if we remove vertices of degree 0 and 1.
3. If vertex $x$ of degree 2 is adjacent to vertices $u$ and $v$,
   then remove vertex $x$, but add edge $uv$.
   As a result the graph remains nonplanar.
4. Let us do operations 2 and 3 as long as
   there remain vertices of degree 2 or less in the graph.
5. As the result we will have graph with no more than 5 vertices,
   and no more than 4 vertices have degree at least 4.
6. It is easy to see that all graphs of order 5 or less,
   where at most four vertices have degree 4, are planar.
   (Say, if we remove one edge in $K_5$ we get a planar graph.)
   The contradiction follows.